# Parsin error causing blank screen

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbyY4.png)

Hello, I am with a problem that my code does not worked, where the cause of error is(Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results) with this do with my app when executed stay with blank screen. My code be reffers to udacity course about network and the all code can be find on the link below. Please I am begginner in progamming i don't know more what do.

(The code what I used)

---

```js
public class QueryUtil {

    /**
     * Sample JSON response for a USGS query
     */
    private static final String SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE = "{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"metadata\":{\"generated\":1462295443000,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-01-31&minmag=6&limit=10\",\"title\":\"USGS Earthquakes\",\"status\":200,\"api\":\"1.5.2\",\"limit\":10,\"offset\":1,\"count\":10},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":7.2,\"place\":\"88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\",\"time\":1454124312220,\"updated\":1460674294040,\"tz\":720,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004vvx\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004vvx&format=geojson\",\"felt\":2,\"cdi\":3.4,\"mmi\":5.82,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":798,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"20004vvx\",\"ids\":\",at00o1qxho,pt16030050,us20004vvx,gcmt20160130032510,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.958,\"rms\":1.19,\"gap\":17,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 7.2 - 88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[158.5463,53.9776,177]},\"id\":\"us20004vvx\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.1,\"place\":\"94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea\",\"time\":1453777820750,\"updated\":1460156775040,\"tz\":600,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004uks\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004uks&format=geojson\",\"felt\":null,\"cdi\":null,\"mmi\":4.1,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":572,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"20004uks\",\"ids\":\",us20004uks,gcmt20160126031023,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":1.537,\"rms\":0.74,\"gap\":25,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.1 - 94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[153.2454,-5.2952,26]},\"id\":\"us20004uks\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.3,\"place\":\"50km NNE of Al Hoceima, Morocco\",\"time\":1453695722730,\"updated\":1460156773040,\"tz\":0,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004gy9\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004gy9&format=geojson\",\"felt\":117,\"cdi\":7.2,\"mmi\":5.28,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":695,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004gy9\",\"ids\":\",us10004gy9,gcmt20160125042203,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":2.201,\"rms\":0.92,\"gap\":20,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.3 - 50km NNE of Al Hoceima, Morocco\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-3.6818,35.6493,12]},\"id\":\"us10004gy9\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":7.1,\"place\":\"86km E of Old Iliamna, Alaska\",\"time\":1453631430230,\"updated\":1460156770040,\"tz\":-540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004gqp\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004gqp&format=geojson\",\"felt\":1816,\"cdi\":7.2,\"mmi\":6.6,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":1496,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004gqp\",\"ids\":\",at00o1gd6r,us10004gqp,ak12496371,gcmt20160124103030,\",\"sources\":\",at,us,ak,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,trump-origin,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.72,\"rms\":2.11,\"gap\":19,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 7.1 - 86km E of Old Iliamna, Alaska\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-153.4051,59.6363,129]},\"id\":\"us10004gqp\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.6,\"place\":\"215km SW of Tomatlan, Mexico\",\"time\":1453399617650,\"updated\":1459963829040,\"tz\":-420,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004g4l\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004g4l&format=geojson\",\"felt\":11,\"cdi\":2.7,\"mmi\":3.92,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":673,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004g4l\",\"ids\":\",at00o1bebo,pt16021050,us10004g4l,gcmt20160121180659,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":2.413,\"rms\":0.98,\"gap\":74,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.6 - 215km SW of Tomatlan, Mexico\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-106.9337,18.8239,10]},\"id\":\"us10004g4l\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.7,\"place\":\"52km SE of Shizunai, Japan\",\"time\":1452741933640,\"updated\":1459304879040,\"tz\":540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004ebx\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004ebx&format=geojson\",\"felt\":51,\"cdi\":5.8,\"mmi\":6.45,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":720,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004ebx\",\"ids\":\",us10004ebx,pt16014050,at00o0xauk,gcmt20160114032534,\",\"sources\":\",us,pt,at,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",associate,cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.281,\"rms\":0.98,\"gap\":22,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.7 - 52km SE of Shizunai, Japan\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[142.781,41.9723,46]},\"id\":\"us10004ebx\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.1,\"place\":\"12km WNW of Charagua, Bolivia\",\"time\":1452741928270,\"updated\":1459304879040,\"tz\":-240,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004ebw\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004ebw&format=geojson\",\"felt\":3,\"cdi\":2.2,\"mmi\":2.21,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":573,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004ebw\",\"ids\":\",us10004ebw,gcmt20160114032528,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":5.492,\"rms\":1.04,\"gap\":16,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.1 - 12km WNW of Charagua, Bolivia\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-63.3288,-19.7597,582.56]},\"id\":\"us10004ebw\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.2,\"place\":\"74km NW of Rumoi, Japan\",\"time\":1452532083920,\"updated\":1459304875040,\"tz\":540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004djn\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004djn&format=geojson\",\"felt\":8,\"cdi\":3.4,\"mmi\":3.74,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":594,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004djn\",\"ids\":\",us10004djn,gcmt20160111170803,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":1.139,\"rms\":0.96,\"gap\":33,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.2 - 74km NW of Rumoi, Japan\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[141.0867,44.4761,238.81]},\"id\":\"us10004djn\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.5,\"place\":\"227km SE of Sarangani, Philippines\",\"time\":1452530285900,\"updated\":1459304874040,\"tz\":480,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004dj5\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004dj5&format=geojson\",\"felt\":1,\"cdi\":2.7,\"mmi\":7.5,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":650,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004dj5\",\"ids\":\",at00o0srjp,pt16011050,us10004dj5,gcmt20160111163807,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":3.144,\"rms\":0.72,\"gap\":22,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.5 - 227km SE of Sarangani, Philippines\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[126.8621,3.8965,13]},\"id\":\"us10004dj5\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6,\"place\":\"Pacific-Antarctic Ridge\",\"time\":1451986454620,\"updated\":1459202978040,\"tz\":-540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004bgk\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004bgk&format=geojson\",\"felt\":0,\"cdi\":1,\"mmi\":0,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":554,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004bgk\",\"ids\":\",us10004bgk,gcmt20160105093415,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":30.75,\"rms\":0.67,\"gap\":71,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.0 - Pacific-Antarctic Ridge\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-136.2603,-54.2906,10]},\"id\":\"us10004bgk\"}],\"bbox\":[-153.4051,-54.2906,10,158.5463,59.6363,582.56]}";

    /**
     * Create a private constructor because no one should ever create a {@link QueryUtil} object.
     * This class is only meant to hold static variables and methods, which can be accessed
     * directly from the class name QueryUtils (and an object instance of QueryUtils is not needed).
     */
    private QueryUtil() {
    }



    /**
     * Return a list of {@link InfosQuake} objects that has been built up from
     * parsing a JSON response.
     */
    public static ArrayList<InfosQuake> extractEarthquakes() {

        // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding earthquakes to
        ArrayList<InfosQuake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();

        // Try to parse the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
        // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
        // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
        try {

            // TODO: Parse the response given by the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE string and
            // build up a list of Earthquake objects with the corresponding data.
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE);

            // Getting json array code.
            JSONArray earthQuakeArrays = root.getJSONArray("Feature");


            // Looping through all infosNodes that we want.
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < earthQuakeArrays.length(); i += 1);
            JSONObject currentEarthQuake = earthQuakeArrays.getJSONObject(i);

            JSONObject properties = currentEarthQuake.getJSONObject("properties");
            String magnitude = properties.getString("mag");
            String location = properties.getString("place");
            String time = properties.getString("time");

            InfosQuake earthquake = new InfosQuake(magnitude, location, time);
            earthquakes.add(earthquake);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
            // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
            // with the message from the exception.
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
        }

        // Return the list of earthquakes
        return earthquakes;
    }
}
```

(The error that is causing)

```js
Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results
                                                                               org.json.JSONException: No value for Feature
                                                                                   at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
                                                                                   at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
                                                                                   at com.example.android.earthquakeapp.QueryUtil.extractEarthquakes(QueryUtil.java:60)
                                                                                   at com.example.android.earthquakeapp.EarthquakeActivity.onCreate(EarthquakeActivity.java:20)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud843/lessons/1335cf7d-bb4f-48c6-8503-f14b127d2abc/concepts/0eca5789-48d7-4662-8e87-d71490519bd4

Comment: Please paste the error messages instead of images, it's not easy to help in image format. Also, you'll need to post a bit of code where the error lies so we can help diagnose it.

Comment: paste the entire code where you are calling the url and manage the response

Comment: @ZeldaZach , I've already put the code and the error. if something is wrong can talk.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse like this below

yours did mistake in getting the array using the key **features** and your didnt loop correctly.

```
public static ArrayList<InfosQuake> extractEarthquakes() {

    ArrayList<InfosQuake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        // TODO: Parse the response given by the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE string and
        // build up a list of Earthquake objects with the corresponding data.
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE);

        // Getting json array code.
        JSONArray earthQuakeArrays = root.optJSONArray("features");

        if (earthQuakeArrays == null) {
            return earthquakes;
        }

        // Looping through all infosNodes that we want.
        for (int i = 0; i < earthQuakeArrays.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentEarthQuake = earthQuakeArrays.optJSONObject(i);

            if (currentEarthQuake == null) {
                continue;
            }
            JSONObject properties = currentEarthQuake.optJSONObject("properties");

            if (properties == null) { // In your case we dont have any other things to get so continue
                continue;
            }

            String magnitude = properties.optString("mag");
            String location = properties.optString("place");
            String time = properties.optString("time");

            InfosQuake earthquake = new InfosQuake(magnitude, location, time);
            earthquakes.add(earthquake);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
        // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
        // with the message from the exception.
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
    }

    // Return the list of earthquakes
    return earthquakes;
}
```